Use the row containing the sought value in an excel file as the dataframe column's titles with xlwings
How can I use the row containing a string as the dataframe column's titles, e.g:
EXCEL DATA:



FIELDS
VALUES




F1
V1


F2
V2


F3
V3


F4
V4



With F2 as sought value, my Dataframe should be as below:



F2
V2




F3
V3


F4
V4



How can I achieve this please, I have tried many scripts with xlwings?
sheet_name='Sheet1'
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet_name.strip())                    
 
search_value='F2'             
row_index=df[df.iloc[:,0]==search_value].index[0]

app = xw.App()
wb = app.books.open(file)     
# Specify the starting row containing the value 
starting_row = row_index  

data_range = wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range(f'A{starting_row}').options(pd.DataFrame, header=True, index=False, expand='table').value
 
wb.close()
 
app.quit()
 
print('############### DATAFRAME #################')
print(data_range)


Don't you just need to offset the row starting_row = row_index? Your search finds 'F2' has an index (row_index) of 0. Xlwings row index starts at 1 and you have the header row. So maybe starting_row = row_index +2 ?

I have used starting_row = row_index +3 and it's ok.
sheet_name='Sheet1'
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet_name.strip())                    
 
search_value='F2'             
row_index=df[df.iloc[:,0]==search_value].index[0]

app = xw.App()
wb = app.books.open(file)     
# Specify the starting row containing the value 
starting_row = row_index  + 3 

data_range = wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range(f'A{starting_row}').options(pd.DataFrame, header=True, index=False, expand='table').value
 
wb.close()
 
app.quit()
 
print('############### DATAFRAME #################')
print(data_range)

